# Scanner reading from txt file stops randomly [JAVA]

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm a student who's trying to fix my code, but I know far too little regarding coding so I'm stuck.

So the objective of my code is to be able to identify words within a text file and after that send these to **my own** implementation of a `HashSet` class and a `TreeSet` class. The text is not suppose to include anything else except letters and whitespaces, which is why the if statements only catch `isLetter` and `isSpaceChar` from the text file.

The issue is that for some reason the for loop which iterates through the entire String (which has all the text stored from the scanner) length, stops at 42. i should increment to about 4500 (total characters in the text file) but stops at 42. I have a character that takes the element located at i in the String variable called *"line"* and then adds all these characters together to form a word whenever a space character is detected. When a space character is detected it is suppose to send the gathered characters, forming a string (a word), to my own classes of `HashSet` and `TreeSet`.

But it only sends about the first 5 words to the classes, and when investigating why it does not send everything, i only goes to 42 and then stops. I have tried using a `StringBuilder` but the results is the same. I have similar looking code in another class where it works flawlessly and does indeed interate through to about 4500. Can someone perhaps pinpoint the flaw that I have become blind to? I've gone over it so many times (comparing this class to my other that works) and I can't see what causes the issue.

The code:

```
try { //A catch that is excluded here
        File words = new File("Path to my text file");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(words);

        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        int counter = 1; //Counting words

        HashWordSet hash = new HashWordSet();
        TreeWordSet tree = new TreeWordSet();
        String thisWord = "";
        while(scan.hasNext()) { //Reading file
            line.append(scan.nextLine()); //Includes the next lines
            line.append(System.lineSeparator());

          
            for (int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++) {
                char ch = line.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                    thisWord = thisWord +ch;
                }
                else if (Character.isSpaceChar(ch)) {
                    //Splitting the text to words to send to the class to create
                    //objects, is the idea
                   
                    Word word = new Word(thisWord);
                    hash.add(word);
                    tree.add(word);

                    thisWord = ""; //Clears String
                    //i stops at 42, whilst list.length is 4504, curious
                }
                System.out.println("Print i: " +i);
            }
```

Some of the text file contents:

> Computer programming History of programming From Wikipedia the free encyclopedia The earliest known programmable machine that is a machine whose behavior can be controlled by changes to a program was AlJazaris programmable humanoid robot in  AlJazaris robot was originally a boat with  four automatic musicians that floated on a lake to entertain guests at royal drinking parties His mechanism had a programmable drum machine with pegs cams that bump into little levers that operate the percussion

Comment: Can you provide your input sample? What strikes me first is that you test for `.isLetter(ch)` with else `.isSpaceChar(ch)` — what happens if you hit a character that is not a letter and is not a space character (e.g. punctuation)? It looks like you ignore it and just advance to the next character, but in noticing this it points out that the issue may depend on the input, so knowing the input would be useful. (which you seem to have added _as I typed this_)

Comment: @StephenP Yes sorry, I edited the post to add the information you asked for. The purpose is indeed to not have any other characters but letters and whitespaces.

Comment: It looks like you read a line of text and append it to the StringBuilder and then process the data in the StringBuilder. But then you append the next line of data to the StringBuilder without first clearing the old data, so you would end up processing the first line a second time. There is no need for the StringBuilder. You can use the `charAt(...)` method of the String class to process each character.  Even easier would be to use the `split(...)` method of the String class to separate the data into words.

Comment: You said it only send 5 words. "Computer programming History of programming". 5th one is programming, which appear twice. All I can think is that in your implementations of HashSet or TreeSet you throw an error. Maybe that error is catched by the try block if not visible to you.